# How to get from 3 phase variable high voltage AC to 230V AC

Tags: voltage-regulator, inverter, generator, ac-dc

I already asked all the electricians in my area (at least 7-8) and nobody could help me, so I am asking you.

I have a [Pelton generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelton_wheel) - a type of water powered generator.

My output is 3 phase variable between 240-360V.
How do I get them to a stable 230V AC (to use for domestic electric items?)

I once had am item that did exactly that and I could simply attach the three AC wires and attach anything "normal at home" on the other side. And it did cost about 150$.

The company that made this doesn't exist anymore and nobody can tell me where to buy a replaceable item.

Attached an image of my generator.

Could somebody explain me how to do this?

[image: My generator]

Comment: You may find it useful to read http://www.ecmweb.com/content/what-know-about-variable-voltage-transformers

Comment: What is your load current range?

Comment: What AC frequency range does it produce?

Comment: Hi, my Pelton generator produces 240V-360V, depending on the spinning speed.
So I need an thing that can candle variable voltage input and puts out a steady 220V AC for common unse in europe.

Comment: You are failing to answer Andy aka's comment: what frequency? e.g. 50 Hz nominal (Europe)? The original "black-box" may have adjusted voltage - maybe a kind of "dimmer switch" - but may not have given out constant frequency and this may cause problems with certain devices when the output frequency changes with Pelton frequency. So, you need to define "steady 220 V AC". What devices do you run from the power generated?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i am very bad at electronics and thank you for the explanation.
50 Hz it is for Italy.
Hopefully that answers the question. Thanks

Comment: Is this meant for running on the grid or for running off-grid? Also, is it a sychronous generator? Does it have an excitation winding or permanent magnets?

Comment: Hi Janka,
it's meant to run off grid. I do not need to save the energy or something. I just need a dehumidifier running all the time. That's it.
It's a permanent magnet generator.

Answer (score 1):

If your generator is permanent magnet, as I suspect based on the varying voltage, the raw power coming from this will not only vary in voltage, but it will vary in frequency too as the water velocity changes. You have two choices here;

1. Vary the water flow so that you achieve a constant speed relating to
   50Hz, then take whatever that resulting voltage is and use a
   transformer to step it up or down to the desired 220V. This is by
   the way difficult to achieve with precision.
2. Take the variable voltage and frequency into a rectifier to make
   DC, then use an inverter to recreate AC from that.